# Spark build generating scala from avro

Tags: java, intellij-idea, apache-spark

The Spark build module spark-streaming-flume-skink uses some avro classes such as SparkFlumeProtocol that don't exist but need to be generated.

There is a project/plugins.sbt defined with

```
    addSbtPlugin("com.cavorite" % "sbt-avro" % "0.3.2")
```

and using

```
sbt assembly
```

does not generate these files. Does anyone know how to do this? The IntelliJ build fails without these scala/java files:

```
Error:(44, 66) not found: type SparkFlumeProtocol val transactionTimeout: Int, val backOffInterval: Int) extends SparkFlumeProtocol with Logging {
```

Answer (score 1):

Turns out you can do this using sbt assembly but it puts the files in a default location. Also you can do

```
mvn generate-sources
```

in folder `externals/flume-sink`